# Better understanding of what is used to feed YOLO

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection, yolo

I'm trying to construct a YOLO dataset.
A read a lot about the dataset and understood many things :

- pc is the confidence and it corresponds to the IoU between predicted and ground truth bboxes
- there are C classes
- there are 4 coordinates times the number of bounding boxes (here only 1).

What I do not understand is this quote drawn from the [YOLO paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1506.02640.pdf) :

> Our final layer predicts both class probabilities and bounding box coordinates. We normalize the bounding box width and height by the image width and height so that they fall between 0 and 1. We parametrize the bounding box x and y coordinates to be offsets of a particular grid cell location so they are also bounded between 0 and 1.

I construct my bbox coordinates as many website and annotation solutions suggest, it leads to : cx, cy, rh, rw which are respectively the bbox center coordinates and the bbox height and width *relative* to the image (normalized by the image size). But this method doesn't seems to rely on the paper's method since cx and cy are note relative *to a grid cell* here.

I read the [Hackernoon article](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-yolo-f5a74bbc7967) but I don't understand how he sets his x and y : he mentions `x=(220-149)/149 = 0.48` where 149 is his grid cell size and 220 is the absolute x coordinate of the bbox. But if there are more cells and one split the image by 6 for instance : `447/6 = 75`, then `x=(220-75)/75 = 1.93` which is not a relative value (greater than 1)...

##### My questions :

- Does that mean that I had to take into account the grid size (and so the grid cell sizes) when I create my dataset ?
- Do I need to include a pc in my training set ? And so, cut the image into cells and return a n*n matrice with 0 and 1 as a pc number ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post here a summary of what has been said and give more context about my initial questions.

#### Bounding box coordinates

First of all, as mentionned by @MichelKok : the initial YOLO model uses offsets **relative to grid cell size** (at the contrary, YOLOv5 does not employ the grid structure anymore).

In YOLOv1, the bounding box regression is applied **into a grid cell**. Therefore input coordinates have to be *relative* to one grid cell . In other words, if an image is "split" into 3x3 grid cells, the first left cell is (0,0) and the botom right is (2,2).

One can implement this as folow :

```py
cell_size = width/S #or height/S
cx_rcell = cx % cell_size / cell_size
cy_rcell = cy % cell_size / cell_size
```

Where :

- `cx` and `cx` are respectively `x` and `y` coordinates of the *center* of the bounding box and are *relative* to the image (i.e. normalized by the with or height).
- `cell_size` is the size of one grid cell, defined by the number of grid cell in one direction `S`

Finally, one can go back to the image relative coordinates :

```py
cx = cx_rcell * cell_size - (1/cell_size) * int(cx_rcell/cell_size)
cy = cy_rcell * cell_size - (1/cell_size) * int(cy_rcell/cell_size)
```

#### YOLOv1 Loss function

There are 4 parts into this loss :

- minimizing the squared error of cx and cy coordinates
- minimizing the root squared error of w and h
- minimizing the squared error of the confidence numbers
- minimizing the squared error of the class probabilities

Note that this loss is constructed in such a way that it penalizes errors **depending if an object appears in the current grid cell**. As I understood it, this means that one need to deal with bounding box coordinate training set as tensors of shape (N, S, S, 5) in order to get the information *"In which cell grid the center of this training bounding box is ?"*.

A simple implementation could be :

```py
bbox_tensor = torch.zeros(N, S, S, 4)
bbox_tensor[int(cy_rcell / cell_size), int(cx_rcell / cell_size)] = torch.Tensor([cx_rcell , cy_rcell, w, h])
```

Here, the bounding box coordinates will be located in the cell (i,j) in S^2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Probably the reason for your confusion is that there is nowadays a whole family of different YOLO models. The initial YOLO model, the one you refer to, uses offsets relative to grid cell size. Nowadays, most people nowadays probably use something like YOLOv5, which does not employ the grid structure anymore. Instead, you get the annotation format that you probably got from most other websites.
2. The Hackernoon article you refer to, can subtract by 149 since the grid cell is actually at (1, 1) in grid coordinates. However, when you are not, you need to compensate for that. So, to compute `x` take the modulo first so as to take off all previous grid cells and then do the relative offset, like so `x = x % g / g` - with `g` being grid size.

Comment: OK, I see. Indeed I was referring to Yolo v1.
So, regarding the pc number, do I need to add a "pc grid" in my training set ?
Thx !

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by pc and how it's relevant. I also cannot find it in either the paper or the Hackernoon article?

Comment: Sorry. Pc is the confidence number. In ne paper, it says that the confidence number is equal to the IoU btw ground truth and predicted bboxes and indicates actually if there is an object to detect or not in this grid cell. What I do not understand is how do I do the loss of this variable.

Comment: Okay, then it's the number that is computed within the model based on the two model outputs and the IoU threshold that you set upfront. You do not need to do anything with that when you define your annotations.

Comment: I do not understand. 
In the paper there the loss formula and we clearly see the squared sum of the confident numbers `p_i(c)^2 - p_i(c)_hat^2` where the "hat" is the ground truth. How do I found this ground truth if I do not modify my annotations ?

Comment: EDIT : I think there is a misunderstanding from myself. In the paper, `p_i(c)` is not the confident score but the *probability* of the class C. I'll come back later and post a decent answer gathering all the information. Thank you :)

Comment: Indeed, it's the confidence of the model so to say. Sure, no problem. Feel free to ask more about it!

Comment: By the way, if you're satisfied, please accept the answer such that people don't get drawn to it when you already know the answer :)